# Azure - App Service Certificate in Key Vault is blank - Unable to download the pfx using powershell / az cli

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I have created an Azure App Service Certificate - Wildcard and have linked it to an Azure Key Vault, also done with Domain Verification. Now I want to export this certificate as PFX and use in other components.

However, If I go to the Key Vault secret it shows up as blank.
[image: This is the blank secret]

I have tried running powershell scripts to export/download the cert but doesn't work.

The powershell script to export the cert from Key Vault is taken from https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/02/24/Creating-a-local-PFX-copy-of-App-Service-Certificate.html
As this used the retired AzureRM module, I found a more up to date code which uses Azure Powershell scripts @ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Anitalex/poshscripts/a7e6c8153ab9f9979792eb8c07497cd42e39778d/azure/ExportWebAppCertificate.ps1
But similar set of steps..

I have tried Re-Keying the certificate in the App Service Certificate and the problem persists ?

Answer (score 1):

Argh...
Here is the solution which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere..

I don't know if it's the only way, but looks like it - We have to

1. Create an Azure WebApp ( or an AppService)
2. Turn on TLS/SSL
3. Set an Identity - either System Assigned/User Assigned
4. Grant this Identity required permission to the KeyVault [ won't work with the Azure role-based access control (preview) ]
5. Go to the tab "Private Key Certificates (.pfx)"
6. Use the "Import App Service Certificate"  - you will need to select your cert from the dropdowns.
7. Once the certificate is successfully imported, the pfx will be populated in the Key Vault certificate and now you can download.